# Which entity allows scoped attributes?

Tags: magento2, attributes, eav-attributes, scope

> /vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/ScopedAttributeInterface.php

There are 3 defined scopes

```
/**
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
interface ScopedAttributeInterface
{
    const SCOPE_STORE = 0;

    const SCOPE_GLOBAL = 1;

    const SCOPE_WEBSITE = 2;
}
```

> and here is the DB for `entity_type_code`

```
mysql> SELECT entity_type_id, entity_type_code FROM eav_entity_type;
+----------------+------------------+
| entity_type_id | entity_type_code |
+----------------+------------------+
|              1 | customer         |
|              2 | customer_address |
|              3 | catalog_category |
|              4 | catalog_product  |
|              5 | order            |
|              6 | invoice          |
|              7 | creditmemo       |
|              8 | shipment         |
+----------------+------------------+
```

> So above all entities, Which Entity Allows scope attributes.

[image]

**`customer` and `customer_address` Does not support Scope Attribute [Global]**

**`catalog_category` and `catalog_product` Does support Scope Attribute [Default, Website and Store]**

> So the question is **Sales tables** does support Scope Attribute ? 
>   Because sales tables are stored as flat tables in Magento.

```
5: order
6: invoice
7: creditmemo
8: shipment
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `customer` and `customer_address` Does not support Scope Attribute
  [Global]
- `catalog_category` and `catalog_product` Does support Scope Attribute
  [Default, Website and Store]

> So the question is, Sales tables does support Scope Attributes? Because
> sales tables are stored as Flat tables in Magento

**Sales DOES NOT support Scope Attributes.**

### [image]

**Confirmation 1 : Check the `eav_entity_type` table in Magento 2**

- `attribute_model` and `entity_attribute_collection` is **NULL** for
  sales related entities.
- Where as Customer Attributes can be created Scope wise.
- Catalog Attributes can be created Scope wise.

**Confirmation 2 : Check `getDefaultEntities` function in `Setup` folder, It clears the doubt.**

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Setup/CustomerSetup.php

```
/**
     * Retrieve default entities: customer, customer_address
     *
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function getDefaultEntities()
    {
        $entities = [
            'customer' => [
                'entity_type_id' => \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
                'entity_model' => \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer::class,
                'attribute_model' => \Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute::class,
                'table' => 'customer_entity',
                'increment_model' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\NumericValue::class,
                'additional_attribute_table' => 'customer_eav_attribute',
                'entity_attribute_collection' => \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\Collection::class,
                'attributes' => [
                    'website_id' => [
                        'type' => 'static',
                        'label' => 'Associate to Website',
                        'input' => 'select',
                        'source' => \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Website::class,
                        'backend' => \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Backend\Website::class,
                        'sort_order' => 10,
                        'position' => 10,
                        'adminhtml_only' => 1,
                    ],
                    'store_id' => [
                        'type' => 'static',
                        'label' => 'Create In',
                        'input' => 'select',
                        'source' => \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Store::class,
                        'backend' => \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Backend\Store::class,
                        'sort_order' => 20,
                        'visible' => false,
                        'adminhtml_only' => 1,
                    ],
```

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Setup/CategorySetup.php

```
/**
     * Default entities and attributes
     *
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function getDefaultEntities()
    {
        return [
            'catalog_category' => [
                'entity_type_id' => self::CATEGORY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID,
                'entity_model' => Category::class,
                'attribute_model' => Attribute::class,
                'table' => 'catalog_category_entity',
                'additional_attribute_table' => 'catalog_eav_attribute',
                'entity_attribute_collection' =>
                    Collection::class,
                'attributes' => [
                    'name' => [
                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'label' => 'Name',
                        'input' => 'text',
                        'sort_order' => 1,
                        'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'group' => 'General Information',
                    ],
```

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Setup/SalesSetup.php

```
/**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDefaultEntities()
    {
        $entities = [
            'order' => [
                'entity_type_id' => self::ORDER_ENTITY_TYPE_ID,
                'entity_model' => \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order::class,
                'table' => 'sales_order',
                'increment_model' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\NumericValue::class,
                'increment_per_store' => true,
                'attributes' => [],
            ],
            'invoice' => [
                'entity_type_id' => self::INVOICE_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TYPE_ID,
                'entity_model' => \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice::class,
                'table' => 'sales_invoice',
                'increment_model' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\NumericValue::class,
                'increment_per_store' => true,
                'attributes' => [],
            ],
            'creditmemo' => [
                'entity_type_id' => self::CREDITMEMO_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TYPE_ID,
                'entity_model' => \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo::class,
                'table' => 'sales_creditmemo',
                'increment_model' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\NumericValue::class,
                'increment_per_store' => true,
                'attributes' => [],
            ],
            'shipment' => [
                'entity_type_id' => self::SHIPMENT_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TYPE_ID,
                'entity_model' => \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment::class,
                'table' => 'sales_shipment',
                'increment_model' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\NumericValue::class,
                'increment_per_store' => true,
                'attributes' => [],
            ],
        ];
        return $entities;
    }
```

**In Conformation 2 - `getDefaultEntities` is Scope wise for Customer Attributes and Catalog as well Categories But Sales DOES NOT support Scope Attributes, It is not defined in Setup.**

Answer (score 7):

As per my understanding you can only create custom attribute for below entity types:

1. Customer (Scope: Global)
2. customer_address (Scope: Global)
3. catalog_category (Scope: Default, Website and Store)
4. catalog_product (Scope: Default, Website and Store)

as when you have a look on `eav_entity_type` table's column `additional_attribute_table` and `entity_attribute_collection` you can see the values for above 4 `entity_types` only.

And for Customer attribute by default scope is **Global (default)** so you don't have to set the scope attribute. For rest i.e Catalog Category and Product you can set any scope i.e **Global (default), Website or Store**

For rest I don't think you can create, but if you want to create extra column for rest of the entity you can use **extension attribute** feature of M2

Comment: Thanks @aman for the answer :) Sales does not have scope attributes